# Laravel 4.2 use Sentinel with Jenssegers MongoDB

Tags: laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb, cartalyst-sentinel

Is it possible to use Cartalyst/Sentinel with Jenssegers/MongoDB on Laravel 4.2?
I'm currently using Sentry, but I want to try Sentinel with new features.

After installation, I tried this:

```
    $user = Sentinel::register([
        'email'              => $email,
        'password'           => $password,
    ]);
```

But I've got the following error:

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar,
>   null given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/shared/muzza/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 1853 and defined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sentinel doesn't have integration with Jenssegers MongoDB lib.

> **Dan Syme commented on 2 Jul:**
>
> You would have to write the implementations for the different models
> used throughout Sentinel.
>
> Then switch out the models for the different entities on the config
> file with your own implementations, Sentinel should take care of
> everything else.
>
> **Maxime-BHA commented on 3 Jul:**
>
> As @jenssegers already did for Sentry package, you have to create your
> own Models extending the originals models from Sentinel and bind the
> attributes defined in those models for relationships/persistances to
> the new models etc.. like static $usersModel =
> 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser'; and also change the config
> file.
>
> See exemple for Sentry there :
> https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb-sentry
>
> I think it's the exact same procedure.

More information you can find [here](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/issues/86).